# Validar un int y pasarlo a string

Tags: c#, consola

Buenas gente, que tal? , Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y tengo una duda

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingresar un tipo");

int unTipo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (unTipo == 1)
{

}
```

Como ven en el código, es una prueba de consola en C# y lo que pide es ingresar un número y que la variable, de acuerdo al numero ingresado esa variable tendría que tomar un valor `String` , Como puedo hacer eso?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Edita bien tu pregunta, haber léela, no se entiende nada.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [Int32.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingresar un tipo");
String input = Console.ReadLine();
    if(Int32.TryParse(input, out opcion))
    {
          switch(opcion) 
          {
               case 1:
                     //Opcion 1
                     break;
               case 2:
                    //Opcion 2
                    break;
               default:
                    Console.WriteLine("No es un tipo valido.");
               break;
          }

    }
```

Pero también puedes tomar el caracter directamente sin convertirlo:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Ingresar un tipo");

    string opcion = Console.ReadLine();
    switch(opcion)
    {
        case "1":
            //Opcion 1
            break;
        case "2":
            //Opcion 2
            break;
        case "3":
            //Opcion 3
            break;
        case "4":
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("No es un tipo valido.");
            break;
    }
```